# Make all files in a folder (and subfolders) expire in a year using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to set expiration headers for all the files in a "media" folder. A file looks like this: `media/css/db38a57a8fa9de240b3ed5eb8be83691`. I want it to be served with headers specifying it is to expire in a year or more.

How do I do that with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First , is mod_expire enabled in apache ? you can setup expiration like this if it's enabled

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 year"
</ifmodule>
```

Files will expire 1 year after they have been last modified , if you whant it based on access you can set it like so :

```
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</ifmodule>
```

Have a look [here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to limit the scope, so I don't have to necessarily place the .htaccess file in the /media folder? I would like to have just one .htaccess file for everything in the root of the project, if possible. :)

Comment: @ Edit: returns error "<Directory not allowed here", oh well, guess I'll just do it the old fashion way. Thx.